# RegExpr confusion with negated character classes?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have the following method:

```
protected BigDecimal stringToBigDecimal(String value) throws ParseException
{
    if (Pattern.matches("[\\d,.]+", value))
    {
        Number n = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(value);

        return new BigDecimal(n.doubleValue());
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ParseException("Invalid String", -1);
    }
}
```

This value throws an exception (as expected), so this regExpr works:

```
String wrongAmount = "1,U35,345.43";
```

But when I try this:

```
protected BigDecimal stringToBigDecimal(String value) throws ParseException
{
    if (Pattern.matches("[\\D&&[^.,]]+", value))
    {
        throw new ParseException("Invalid String", -1);
    }

    Number n = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(value);

    return new BigDecimal(n.doubleValue());
}
```

No exception is thrown, but why? 
First I thought that there is a logical problem with the "except for" expression so I tried this value with this pattern:

```
String wrongAmount = "1U3534543";

protected BigDecimal stringToBigDecimal(String value) throws ParseException
{
    if (Pattern.matches("[\\D]+", value))
    {
        throw new ParseException("Invalid String", -1);
    }

    Number n = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(value);

    return new BigDecimal(n.doubleValue());
}
```

...but this doesn't match? What did I understand wrong on the "non-digit expression" `\\D.`. The value contains an "U", so why doesn't it match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are  not properly negating you expressions.

In the first example, you say "if my input matches only digits, commas and dots", then it's ok.

In your second example (and I am not sure that it does what you meant but that's another story), you meant to say "if the input matches only non-digits, non-commas, non-dots chars", but your input contains digits, so the match won't work.

In your last example, same thing, you are saying "if the input matches only non-digit chars" but again you have digits in your input

Comment: The second example doesn't really say that. Read my answer.

Comment: The character class is *valid*, it's just not doing what you and the OP think it's doing.

Answer (score 2):

Let's dissect each one of your patterns:

```
Pattern.matches("[\\d,.]+", value)
```

Match any string that consists of one or more digits, commas and dots.

```
Pattern.matches("[\\D&&[^.,]]+", value)
```

You can't "combine" character classes like you are doing here. What you're really saying with `[\\D&&[^.,]]` is "match any non-digit character, *except* the dot and comma." The correct way to write that regex would be:

```
[^\\d,.]   # match anything but digits, comma and dot
```

Last but not least:

```
Pattern.matches("[\\D]+", value)
```

This means: "match a non-empty string consists *entirely* of non-digit characters."

`Pattern.matches()` tries to match the *entire* string against a regular expression. You want to use `Matcher.find()` instead if you're trying to match only part of the string.

Finally, you are misunderstanding how the `+` works. `+` is a quantifier that means "1 or more." It's not doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: But matches() would match if I put the plus-sign after the character class as I do. And Javadoc says that you can combine character classes: docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html "[a-z&&[^bc]] a through z, except for b and c: [ad-z] (subtraction)"

Comment: Ok, Matcher.find() would probably a solution too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
if (value.matches(".*[^\\d.,].*")) {
    throw new ParseException("Invalid String", -1);
}
```

Note the added `".*"` to the front and back, because `String.matches()` returns `true` only if the pattern matches the *entire* input.

However I would change it to a negative match because it's easier to read:

```
if (!value.matches("[\\d.,]+")) {
    throw new ParseException("Invalid String", -1);
}
```